# Cannot reference Navigator from React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and I don't know why I cannot reference the Navigator object. I'm getting an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating _this2.refs._navigator.push)`. After one second, when my `setTimeout` function triggers, the error occurs.

Appreciate any help

Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
// ... some code initialization...

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.refs._navigator.push(routes[1]);
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={routes[0]}
        initialRouteStack={routes}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
          switch (route.index) {
            case 0:
              return <Home />;
            case 1:
              return <About />;
            default:
              return <Home />;
          }
        }}
        ref={(nav) => { this._navigator = nav; }}
      />
    );
  }

}

const routes = [
  {title: 'Home', index: 0},
  {title: 'About', index: 1},
  {title: 'Cars', index: 2}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this._navigator.push(routes[1]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

This is because you are referencing the nav as this._navigator in your Navigator ref.

Comment: Hey @Nader, thank you so much. This seems a bit confusing to me, because, in pure React, I must put the "refs" word in order to get this. By the way. Thank you.

Comment: @PabloDarde Not really, you are assigning the `this._navigator` in the ref callback, so it is available there

Comment: Oh, you are right, maybe, the 'refs' keyword were necessary for the deprecated way of reference an element, such as:
**deprecated**
<Element ref='myElement'...

**recommended**
<Element ref={(el) => { this.element = el; }} ...

thanks

Comment: `this.refs` would make sense if you did `<Navigator ref="nav" />`. Then you can do `this.refs.nav`